# Why a node with only one child is impossible in Huffman Tree?

Tags: huffman-code

To construct a coding tree, we must avoid prefix coding in order not to encounter ambiguous meaning.
So, we should have the encoded characters be leaves.
But why it's impossible for a node to have only one child, it does meet the requirement and not cause the ambiguity.
I konw Huffman algorithm that constructs the coding tree from buttom to top can't make it happen.

Are there another encoding algorithms can make encoding tree node have only one child?

Comment: Can't make heads or tails out of your question. You need to rewrite it.

Comment: An "empty" child implies there is a child deeper in the tree than it needs to be, contradicting the optimality of the supposed Huffman tree. You can build *a* tree with a one-child node, but it won't be a Huffman tree by definition.

Answer (score 0):

I can only make sense out the last line of your question. If a node has only one child, then you end up with an unused code or codes, since only the 0 or 1 branch occurs. Codes with a 1 or 0 respectively in that position have no meaning or use. (Note that there is no ambiguity problem here. It is just that some sequences of bits cannot be decoded.)

There is no reason to not collapse that node and its child to just the child, eliminating the unused code. If there were an encoding algorithm that could result in such a situation, it would be producing suboptimal codes. That could easily be remedied by applying another trivial algorithm to go through and collapse those cases, eliminating the problem, using all the codes, and improving the compression.